# How to show all the duplicates Account Names?

Tags: soql, query, duplicate-management, aggregateresult

While running the following query it returns only one duplicate account name but not all the accounts that has the same name.How to get other matching duplicate names?

```
acc = [SELECT Name,count(id),AccountNumber FROM Account GROUP BY Name,AccountNumber HAVING count(Name)>1];
```

> Result while adding inner loops:

```
   Set<String> duplicateNames = new Set<String>();
Public DuplicateAccNames()
{
acc = [SELECT Name,count(id) FROM  Account group by Name having  count(Name)>1];
System.debug('acc count'+acc);
//acc = [select  id,Name,AccountNumber, Phone from Account group by id,name,AccountNumber,Phone having count(Name)>1 ];
for(AggregateResult ac1 : acc)
{
duplicateNames.add((String)ac1.get('Name'));
List<Account> duplicates = [SELECT Name, AccountNumber
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name IN :duplicateNames];
 System.debug('test'+duplicates[1].Name);
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you're getting a `List<AggregateResult>`. You need a `List<Account>` if you want to see the individual records. Probably the simplest way to take what you have already and get what you want is to collect a `Set<String> duplicateNames` then add another query.

```
Set<String> duplicateNames = new Set<String>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [/*existing query*/])
{
    duplicateNames.add((String)aggregate.get('Name'));
}
for (Account account : [
    SELECT Name, AccountNumber
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name IN :duplicateNames
]){
    system.debug(account.AccountNumber);
}
```

Comment: And we have to do this because we can't do: `select id, name from account where name in (select name from account group by name having count(id) > 1)`. Silly SOQL.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah added flexibility on inner-joins would be slick. But it would probably still have to be on indexed fields for performance reasons. I wonder if there's an Idea out there for that.

Comment: Nope@adrian and sfdcfox,.Its still returning only the count expr0 as 2 but not both the names

Comment: You need to look at the `List<Account>`, which doesn't use `count` or `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`. You won't get individual records when you use aggregation.

Comment: Yeah but its returning multiple account Names instead of 4.I have update my Question

Comment: @Pri Perhaps you will find my updated example less confusing.

Comment: Thanks@AdrianLarson.Its displaying perfectly for records that has exact matches with all fields..Others With same Name  are just displaying once.Why is that?and even this 4 records are not getting displayed in order.it retrieves some other duplicate records in between and displays the remaining matched record again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44073/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-pri).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you ?

```
SELECT Name,count(id),AccountNumber FROM Account GROUP BY CUBE( Name,AccountNumber) HAVING count(Name)>1

List<AggregateResult> aggregate =   [SELECT Name,count(id),AccountNumber FROM Account GROUP BY CUBE( Name,AccountNumber) HAVING count( Name)>1 ];
system.debug ((string)aggregate[0].get('AccountNumber'));
```